# It is hard to understand to a transform foldr in cartesian product

Tags: haskell, lambda, functional-programming, fold, cartesian-product

I follow [On Barron and Strachey's cartesian product function](https://tidsskrift.dk/brics/article/download/21934/19359) to understand the combination of high order function.

There is a important transform I got and I think it is not easy to understand it straightforward:

```
h [] xss = []
h (x : xs) xss =
 foldr f (h xs xss) xss where 
    f xs ys = (x: xs) : ys
```

to equal this :

```
h'' xs xss = 
foldr g [] xs where
    g x zss = foldr f zss xss where 
        f xs ys = (x : xs) : ys
```

Even I got these helper:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr f z [] = z
foldr f z (a:as) = f a (foldr f z as) 

-- change the name
h' :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
h' f z [] = z
h' f z (a:as) = f a (h' f z as)
```

So my question is: Is it easy to explain the transform?

Comment: It would be quite helpful to provide the types of `h` and `h''` too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by making an inner function without the second argument `xss` that does the standard list recursion only:

```
h []     xss = []
h (x:xs) xss = foldr f (h xs xss) xss
  where 
    f xs ys = (x:xs) : ys

  -->

h xs xss = h' xs
  where
    h' []     = []
    h' (x:xs) = foldr f (h' xs) xss
      where
        f xs ys = (x:xs) : ys
```

Then let's see how we abstract out the recursion pattern in `h'` with another helper function that acts on `x` and the recursive call result `h' xs` only:

```
h xs xss = h' xs
  where
    h' []     = []
    h' (x:xs) = g x (h' xs)
    g x zss = foldr f zss xss
      where 
        f xs ys = (x:xs) : ys
```

which is just that helper function that we would pass to `foldr` if we didn't want to explicitly write out the list recursion in `h'`:

```
h xs xss = foldr g [] xs
  where
    g x zss = foldr f zss xss
      where 
        f xs ys = (x:xs) : ys
```

Comment: the helper func `g` is like `f` in the definition of `foldr` which `f` is a arg need to be pass. Here `g` just put there as in runtime. Very good and clear.

Comment: In case anybody want to have a look: https://gist.github.com/jiamo/682fc4168791869b23439787a2aeaaab

Answer (score 3):

Essentially it boils down to the fact that `h` is a recursive function on `xs` and that `foldr` generalizes recursion on lists. Note how `h` calls itself on the tail `xs`, much like `foldr` calls itself on the tail `as`.

---

By induction on `ws`, prove that `h ws xss = h'' ws xss`. Reasoning by induction, there are two cases to consider.

**Base case**, `ws = []`

```
h [] xss = []  -- by definition of h

h'' [] xss
= foldr g [] xss  -- by definition of h''
= []              -- by definition of foldr
```

**Induction step**, `ws = x : xs`, assuming `h xs xss = h'' xs xss` (induction hypothesis)

```
h (x : xs) xss
= foldr f (h xs xss) xss    -- by definition of h (N.B. f depends on x)
= foldr f (h'' xs xss) xss  -- by induction hypothesis
= g x (h'' xs xss)          -- by definition of g (N.B. g depends on xss)
= g x (foldr g [] xs)       -- by definition of h''
= foldr g [] (x : xs)       -- by definition of foldr
= h'' (x : xs) xss          -- by definition of h''
```